# AngularJS $modal hoverover popup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like a hover-over popup that displays only when I'm hovering over an element on the screen.  I'm currently using $modal for modals and thought maybe I could use it.  The problem I'm running into is that I'm not sure how to get the modal to go away when I'm not over the page element anymore.  There won't be any action required within the modal, I just want it to appear when I'm over an element and disappear when I move off the element.

Here is my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3vWVRA0CM7vrMugImgmX?p=preview

Here is an example of what I'm looking for using jQuery: http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/jquery-hover-box

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$modal', '$scope', '$log',
    function ($modal, $scope, $log) {
      $scope.option = {
        name: 'Name (hover over for more details)',
        longDescription: 'This is my detailed description...  lots of text here'
      }
       $scope.showOptionDetails = function(option) {
            $log.info($scope.option);
            $scope.optionModal = $modal.open({
                template: '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">Option</h3></div><div class="modal-body">{{option.longDescription}}</div><div class="modal-footer"></div>',
                controller: 'modalCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    option: function() {
                      return $scope.option;
                    }
                }
            });
       }

        $scope.closeOptionDetails = function() {
            $scope.optionModal.close();
        }
      }
  ]);

  myApp.controller('modalCtrl', [
    '$modalInstance', '$scope', '$log', 'option', function ($modalInstance, $scope, $log, option) {
      $log.info(option);
      $scope.option = option;
    }
]);
```

Comment: The reason the mouse leave event isn't firing is because `ng-mouseleave="closeOptionDetails"` should be `ng-mouseleave="closeOptionDetails()"`. But you're still not going to get the behavior you want as the modal disappears as soon as it's created. Would a popover suit your needs?

Comment: Yes a popover would suit my needs I think.  Some of these may get complex though with multiple fields of long text and an image.  Can I use a template with a popover?

Comment: I have given up on a popover with an html template.  Too many examples online that just do not work.  Guess I'm going to have to require users to click a button and get a traditional modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks dude - this is exactly what I was looking for!

The problem was, the ng-mouseleave was in the wrong place and with the wrong controller.  In the modal controller, you need to specifically create a function to call $modalInstance.close().

I took the liberty of adding a close button (so someone can deliberately close the model if they want, but you can remove that.  The mouseleave definitely works!)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$modal', '$scope', '$log',
    function ($modal, $scope, $log) {
      $scope.option = {
        name: 'Name (hover over for more details)',
        longDescription: 'This is my detailed description...  lots of text here'
      }
       $scope.showOptionDetails = function(option) {
            $log.info($scope.option);
            $scope.optionModal = $modal.open({
                template: '<div class="modal-header" ng-mouseleave="close()"><h3 class="modal-title">Option</h3></div><div class="modal-body">{{option.longDescription}}</div><div class="modal-footer" ng-click="close()">Close</div>',
                controller: 'modalCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    option: function() {
                      return $scope.option;
                    }
                }
            });
       }

        $scope.closeOptionDetails = function() {
            $scope.optionModal.close();
        }
      }
  ]);

  myApp.controller('modalCtrl', [
    '$modalInstance', '$scope', '$log', 'option', function ($modalInstance, $scope, $log, option) {
      $log.info(option);
      $scope.option = option;
        $scope.close = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        }
    }
]);
```

You can see it work here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3KiZdZsxwy6GDLoy6DhV?p=preview

Comment: Most welcome! It was good to brush up on angular mouse movements and scope. I guess I had better check out what angular 2 is going to fix, and break...